Computer won't boot into BIOS
I have an Ubuntu  machine built by Lambda labs with 3 Gpus.
When I try SSHing into it, I can use the computer, but the system keeps killing processes that use the GPUs.
When I plug into a monitor, the computer boots up into Ubuntu, but then after about 30 seconds the GUI dies and goes back to login screen. This happens in a cycle.
Both of the above indicate to me (please correct me if I am wrong) there is something wrong with GPU drivers.
I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. I have a USB boot drive that I have verified works. However when I plug in the drive and try booting into the BIOS, the monitor just says no signal and I can't see anything. I have tried all the available HDMI ports in the machine. I also have verified independently that the monitor works.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

If you have more than one connector for monitors, try the others.

Thank you @Bodo for the suggestion. I have already tried that. Will edit my question to say so

in addition to your hdmi ports, you may have an usb-C one dedicated to output at great speed your "main" physical gpu output ? (some manufactors do that) : you could try to plug that one into a monitor (with usually a cable with those connectors: male usb-c <----> male usb-A)

maybe you have a power supply issue

@jsotola I don't think so. When I ssh into it things seem normal. Seems more graphical

I find the command systemctl reboot --firmware-setup is easier than trying to press the correct key at boot, especially with monitors that automatically sleep. Can you boot a live USB, open a terminal, and try that instead? If you have a monitor / cable issue the machine will wait for you to fix that and then you'll see the BIOS / UEFI screen.

The solution was to unplug two gpus. Turns out one of them was corrupt. Now things are working and I can boot into the BIOS
